# How to default contact's country in mailing address based on record type

Tags: country-and-state

Hi we have a few record type that is separate by country. Is there a way that when I am creating a new Account record, I want to default the Country value based on the record type?

For example: if I create an Account record using Canada record type then I want to default the Mailing Country/Billing Country to Canada

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve your issue using:

> By creating a workflow which updates the Country field depending on
>   the record type selected.

Comment: Actually, you can't restrict state and country picklist values by record type.